# Bearer security definition not showing up Swagger .NET 8

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, .net-8.0

i was setting up a new .NET 8 API, using Identity to handle the authentication process.
I'm having a problem while setting up the bearer token auth in swagger.

So after looking around i come up with this:

```
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
{
    options.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
    {
        Name = "Authorization",
        In = ParameterLocation.Header,
        Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey
    });
    
    options.OperationFilter<SecurityRequirementsOperationFilter>();
});
```

I write down the bearer
[Swagger bearer inserted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9U6Wb.png)
But no authorization is available
[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/17ewT.png)

As far as i know Authorization/Identity changed in NET 8, and older videos might be outdated

Other lines of my Program.cs related to the bearer are this:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication().AddBearerToken(IdentityConstants.BearerScheme);
builder.Services.AddAuthorizationBuilder();

builder.Services.AddIdentityCore<User>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<DatabaseContext>()
    .AddApiEndpoints();
```

Maybe they are messing up something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This configuration works for me:

```
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
{
    options.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
    {
        In = ParameterLocation.Header,
        Description = "Please enter a valid token",
        Name = "Authorization",
        Type = SecuritySchemeType.Http,
        BearerFormat = "JWT",
        Scheme = "Bearer"
    });
    options.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
    {
        {
            new OpenApiSecurityScheme
            {
                Reference = new OpenApiReference
                {
                    Type=ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                    Id="Bearer"
                }
            },
            new string[]{}
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes, it works also for me. Probably it was not a valid configuration. Thanks for the help